# How do I cleanup in uwsgi after nginx so_keepalive timeout?

Tags: python, nginx, wsgi, uwsgi

My nginx configuration is like:

```
server {
    listen 80 so_keepalive=30m::;

    location /wsgi {
        uwsgi_pass  uwsgicluster;
        include     uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_read_timeout 30000;
        uwsgi_buffering off;
    }

    ...
}
```

In my python:

```
def application_(environ, start_response):
    body = queue.Queue()
    ...
    gevent.spawn(redis_wait, environ, body, channels)
    return body

def redis_wait(environ, body, channels):
    server = redis.Redis(connection_pool=REDIS_CONNECTION_POOL)

    client = server.pubsub()

    try:
        for channel in channels:
            client.subscribe(channel)

        messages = client.listen()

        for message in messages:
            if message['type'] != 'message' and message['type'] != 'pmessage':
                continue

            body.put(message['data'])
    finally:
        client.unsubscribe()
        client.close()
```

The problem occurs when the client connection is interrupted (either network connection abruptly lost, application terminates, etc.) redis shows that the connection on the server is still open. How do I fix this? Even with the so_keepalive, the connection isnt being cleaned up. How do I fix this?

EDIT: I've noticed through the `nginx_status` page that the active connection count *does* go down after the disconnect. The problem is that uwsgi isnt getting notified of this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait on the uwsgi socket as well as the redis socket so that you can be notified in case the uwsgi socket closes. Example here: http://nullege.com/codes/show/src%40k%40o%40kozmic-ci-HEAD%40tailer%40__init__.py/72/uwsgi.connection_fd/python